# React e.preventDefault() error, onClick passing value from map

Tags: reactjs, arrays, preventdefault

```
    const onSubmit = (event, val) => {
    console.log(val);
    event.preventDefault();
    setValues({ ...values, error: "", success: "", key: val });
    setDidSubmit(true);
  };
```

Using map in React:

```
{data.map((e) => ( <li key={e._id}> <button
                        onClick={(e) => onSubmit(e, e._id)}
                        className="btnx btn-primary"
                      >
                        Book Now logout
                      </button> </li> )}
```

`onClick` I want to pass unique id e._id to the onSubmit function.

But I'm getting output as undefined.

[image: undefined and values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit :-  can you also please provide the output of e argument that you passed into the map callback ?

onClick takes a callback function and pass event as its parameter . Now , here the problem what if i want take some other parameter , to overcome this problem we have to wrap the function (can be accomplished by anonymous function or some other defined function in the code ) -> this step you did the correct but  thing you did  wrong is that you did not accounting the onClick callback default parameter i.e event . so you must account the event parameter in your wrapping function , then you can able to access the event object.

I hope so you get the answer.

```
{data.map((e) => ( <li key={e._id}> <button
                        onClick={(event) => onSubmit(event, e._id)}
                        className="btnx btn-primary"
                      >
                        Book Now logout
                      </button> </li> )}
```